# Display grid different depending on device

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

i am using twitter bootstrap3 and i want to make something very common, a table of products that will resize depending of the device width.

I am using (xs,sm,md,lg) to determine when i should resize the table. This is an example:

I have 8 products and on LG and MD, i want to disply 4 products on every line. On SM and XS i want to see 2 products on every line.

Here is my html code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col col-lg-3 border">
        <img src="img/product1.jpg">          
    </div>
    <div class="col col-lg-3 border"><img src="img/product2.jpg"></div>
    <div class="col col-lg-3 border"><img src="img/product3.jpg"></div>
    <div class="col col-lg-3"><img src="img/product4.jpg"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">        
    <div class="col col-lg-3 border">
        <img src="img/product5.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col col-lg-3 border"><img src="img/product6.jpg"></div>
    <div class="col col-lg-3 border"><img src="img/product7.jpg"></div>
    <div class="col col-lg-3"><img src="img/product8.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

Css code:

```
.border {
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
```

As you can see, first 3 elements have a class called border (i want to separate them with a vertical lign)

So what i have on LG and MD screens is like this:

```
P1 | P1 | P3 | P4
P5 | P6 | P7 | P8
```

And what i want for SM and XS screens is this:

```
P1 | P2
P3 | P4
P5 | P6
P7 | P8
```

How can i do this?

Comment: I know it is a long question, but i am very sure that for an bootstrap3 advanced proggramer it's a piece of cake. So please dont think that because this is a long question, it's a hard one. I hope that there is a solution for this, because this thing that i try to make is something very essential, and if bootstrap can't do it, it's worthless and i have to move on another responsive platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the corresponding class names for md,sm and xs. This is described in http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid .

Since this is a 12 column grid system, if you need two columns then you give the value 6 = 12/2 to the sm and xs. For md to have four columns then the same as with lg it should be 3 = 12/4.
Therefore the code should be as follows,

http://jsfiddle.net/CcAe5/3/show/

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 border">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />          
    </div>
    <div class="col col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 border"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" /></div>
    <div class="col col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 border"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" /></div>
    <div class="col col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 "><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" /></div>
</div>
<div class="row">        
    <div class="col col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 border">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
    </div>
    <div class="col col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 border"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" /></div>
        <div class="col col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 border"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" /></div>
        <div class="col col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" /></div>
</div>
```

**EDIT 1**

After the last comments if there is a requirement to simply show an arbitrary amount of elements in a four column grid in medium and large screen sizes and two column in small and extra small sizes then there should not be any division of elements into *"row"* elements. So the code could be,

```
<div class="col col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 border">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />          
</div>
<div class="col col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 border"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" /></div>
<div class="col col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 border"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" /></div>

<div class="col col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 border">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
</div>
<div class="col col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 border"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" /></div>
    <div class="col col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 border"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" /></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5ahga/1/show/

**EDIT 2**

Following the last comments on borders, one possible solution is to figure out which elements belong to the 4 column border layout and which belong to the 2 column border layout. The code below adds the corresponding classes.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var fourColElems=$('.border').filter(function(i){return (i+1)%4!=0;});
    fourColElems.addClass("lg-md-border");

    var twoColElems = $('.border').filter(function(i){return (i+1)%2!=0;});
    twoColElems.addClass("sm-xs-border");
});
```

The classes added will be activated based on the screen resolution, so with a bit of media queries everything will work as required.

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {/*Small devices Tablets (≥768px)*/
     .border{
        border-right:none;
     }
   .sm-xs-border{
     border-right : 1px solid red; 
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {/*Medium devices Desktops (≥992px)*/
     .border{
        border-right:none;
     }
   .lg-md-border{
     border-right : 1px solid green; 
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2RWLW/show/

*Furthermore if it is required to split the elements evenly depending on the amount of elements i.e. 6 elements can not be split evenly in 4 columns but dynamically a 3 column grid should be displayed or if there are 7 elements use 7 columns. Then you require to modify the class name in runtime with jquery, by doing some calculations first.*

Comment: Thx for the reply. This is not a good solution because, i give you an example: If you have 6 products and on LG and MD you have 3 elements/row (meaning 2 lines with 3 elements on every row) and on SM and XS we need to put 2 elements/row (meaning 3 rows with 2 elements on every row), your solution is not working because it will appear 4 rows (on first row we will have 2 products, on second row we will have 1 product, on third row we will have 2 products and on fourth row we will have 1 product) and as i already wrote the correct number of rows is 3 with 2 products on each row.

Comment: @CrisanRalucaTeodora updated the answer based on your last comments. The first answer was based on the assumption that the row elements were required and that the spliting occurred in that context. If all elements should behave as a single set then no need for row element and i think it behaves as you require.

Comment: This works indeed, but the thing that do now works properly is the border thing. All the elements have a border but that is not correct. On LG only elements 1,2,3,5,6 should have a right border (because the 4 element is in the right margin - not suposed to have border) and on XS devices only elements 1,3,5 should have a right botder because the other ones are in the right margin

Comment: @CrisanRalucaTeodora updated the answer to follow the border scheme you require.

Comment: Your answere was very helpfull, thanks. Do you think that this question will help others also? You find it a good question?

Comment: @CrisanRalucaTeodora certainly, it showcases and explains a very common problem, displaying items in a responsive grid. I should have upvoted earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `md` and `xs` classes since they control the *smallest* of the responsive grid ranges you need to control..

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 border">p1</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 border">p2</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 border">p3</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">p4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">        
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 border">p5</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 border">p6</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 border">p7</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">p8</div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/93453

Comment: Hi again. Thanks for your reply, but this answere is helpfull, as you can already see, i commented to the other response that in some cases this is not working properly, and i need an universal solution because i don't know if my client won't change up his mind the next minute. This problem that i comed up with, from my point of view is critical, it's something very esential, a simple list of products (displayerd responsive) that at the current time seem so hard to accomplish.